# trying to trim and lowercase my String in rust

Tags: string, rust, memory-management

I'm trying to trim and lowercase my String.

Currently I have

```rust
use dialoguer::Input;
    
let input: String = Input::new()
    .with_prompt("Guess a 5 letter word")
    .interact_text()
    .unwrap(); 
let guess: &str = input.as_str(); // trim and lowercase
```

I'm trying to transform `String` into a trimmed and lowercased `&str` but some functions are only on `&str` and others only on `String` so I'm having trouble coming up with an elegant solution.

TL;DR: End goal have `guess` be a trimmed and lowercase `&str`

Comment: String derefs to &str, so you can access str methods from String and if you want a &str as result, just do `&input[..]`

Answer (score 13):

Rust stdlib is not about elegance, but about correctness and efficiency.

In your particular case, `trim()` is defined as `str::trim(&self) -> &str` because it always returns a substring of the original string, so it does not need to copy or allocate a new string, just compute the begin and end, and do the slice.

But `to_lowercase()` is defined as `str::to_lowercase(&self) -> String` because it changes each of its characters to the lowercase equivalent, so it must allocate and fill a new `String`.

You may thing that if you own the string you can mutate it to lowercase in-place. But that will not work in general because there is not a 1-to-1 map between lowercase and uppercase letters. Think of, for example `ß <-> SS` in German.

Naturally, you may know that your string only has ASCII characters... if so you can also use `str::make_ascii_lowercase(&mut self)` that does the change in-place, but only for ASCII characters that do have the 1-to-1 map.

So, summing up, the more ergonomic code would be, to trim `input` and copy to an owned lowercase:

```
let guess : String = input.trim().to_lowercase();
```

Or if you absolutely want to avoid allocating an extra string, but you are positive that only ASCII characters matter:

```
let mut input = input; //you could also add the mut above
input.make_ascii_lowercase();
let guess: &str = input.trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let s = "   aBcD ";
let s2 = s.trim().to_lowercase();
println!("[{s}], [{s2}]");
```

The above will work if `s` is `&str` (as in my example) or `String` and it will print:

```
[   aBcD ], [abcd]
```

So the last line in your code (if you insist on having `guess` as `&str`) should become:

```
let guess: &str = &input.trim().to_lowercase();
```

Otherwise if you write just:

```
let guess = input.trim().to_lowercase();
```

, `guess` will be of type `String`, as that's what `to_lowercase()` returns.

Comment: I think it is also important to point out that since a `&str` is more or less just a reference to a `String` you can implicitly get a `&str` from a `String` when calling functions, but not the other way around. Since most string manipulation functions return a `String`, these functions can be easily chained together.

Comment: @Locke Good point!